# find registry key through a java program from another application

Tags: java, windows, registry

We have an old .net program that makes registry keys.
I don't know the code for the program, but it makes keys for an 32 bit machine with windows xp on

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\TESTPROGRAM\INSTALL\PROG1`

But if you install the same on a 64 bit pc with windows 7 the key is at:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TESTPROGRAM\INSTALL\PROG1`

Now I just installed it at windows 8 and the key is installed in another location at:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TESTPROGRAM\INSTALL\PROG1`

It seems the old .net program automatically knows where to install the keys and also where to read the keys from. Because I don't know the code I don't know what it uses to read the keys.

But I have to read the same keys from java.

At the moment I use the system command `reg query` to do this.

Is there an option to automatically detect which entry he has to search the key for in java?